# Using sed to replace a pattern matched with an exported variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

How can I use `sed` to replace the matched pattern with `EXPORT` variable? Or is there a way I can access shell script variables when invoking `sed` file?

#### shell_cript.sh

```
for i in ./data/*.sav;
do
    read_input (){
        read number_one number_two
        read date1 inventory
        read price
    } < $i
    read_input
    export number_one
    export i
    export number_two
    export inventory
    export price
    sed -f test.sed $2
done
```

#### test.sed

```
s/Filename/$i/g
s/1stplace/$number_one/g
s/2ndplace/$number_two/g
s/\$\$\$\$/$price/g
```

#### file.sav

```
Jonathan Lee
12/12/2019 2
1000
```

Comment: It seems weird for new Stack Overflow users but *"thank-you comments"* should generally be avoided ;) Check [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment) on the subject

Answer (score 0):

If you put all your sed commands in a sed script file, you will not be able to pass variables to it.

What you need to do is pass all your sed commands at the command line level and use double quotes `"` to have your bash/shell interpret the `$` and do the proper variable substitutions. You do not need to `export` the variables as the variable substitution will be done by the shell before creating your `sed` subprocess.

```
sed 's/Filename/'"$i"'/g;s/1stplace/number_one/g;s/2ndplace/number_two/g;s/\$\$\$\$/price/g'
```

Comment: You also need to backslash `$` to match it literally.

Comment: @tripleee: OMG!!!! You are completely right, otherwise it is just the EOL anchor. Fixed! I was focusing to much on the shell interpreting it as a variable. Thank you!

Comment: So I know that in awk we can use ENVIRON [" data"] to access export variables, I just wonder if I can do the same with sed without pass it at the command line level, but thanks though

Comment: @Kevin: unfortunately such feature does not exist in `sed` at the moment.